# Leave Google Talk pop-out window open when closing parent site

Tags: gmail, google-plus, google-talk

I’m using Google Talk from within Google Mail and Google+. However, I actually don’t want to have the parent site (Google Mail or Google+) open all the time while chatting, I just want the pop-out window with the chat.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I realise that this is technically challenging but maybe there’s a “standalone” Google Talk client (outside [the one for Windows](http://www.google.com/talk/), since I’m on OS X) or browser extension?

Comment: More than five years later, there still isn’t an acceptable solution to this problem: all existing “desktop” clients are terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Chrome web browser, Google released a free add-on for the browser that will open chat windows without requiring an application download.

[Chat for Google - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd)